# kernel.panic_on_oops is set yet kernel doesn't panic on oops

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I've set `kernel.panic_on_oops` to 1 via the Kernel command line (by passing `oops=panic`) yet it doesn't seem to panic on generating an oops. I've checked via sysctl if the option is indeed set and it is.

So I'm unable decipher what could be causing this.

Comment: It makes all `WARN*()` to behave like a `BUG()`. Does it mean the user still can access the system after the Oops happened?

Comment: Yes. I'll update the question with more details

Comment: If in addition to `sysctl kernel.panic_on_oops` you also have 0 (the default) or some long value set in `sysctl kernel.panic`, you might just be waiting around for the panic reboot to actually occur ,,, which could happen much later or never.  Try setting this to 30sec or something reasonable enough to allow a vmcore to be generated, but definitely greater than 0, to see if you panic+reboot.

Comment: @FrankHoeflich ok. So I was under the impression that this `kernel.panic` system control knob is a bool. Now that I know that it represents an upper limit on the time it takes to generate a vmcore, I will surely try this and get back to you.

Additionally, I do not want a reboot as I have a debugger attached over the (virtual) serial port, running inside a VM. Do I need to set another config option to ensure we do `not` reboot on panic?

Comment: Ok. Looks like setting a positive value helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in addition to sysctl `kernel.panic_on_oops` (see [1](https://docs.kernel.org/next/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html#panic-on-oops)) you also have 0 (the default) or some long value set in sysctl `kernel.panic` (see [2](https://docs.kernel.org/next/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html#panic)), you might just be waiting around for the panic reboot to actually occur, which could happen much later or never. Try setting this to 30 seconds or something reasonable enough to allow a vmcore to be generated, but definitely greater than 0, to see if you panic+reboot.

Comment: Additionally, I've been struggling with the `udev` daemon vis-à-vis kgdb over serial connection. After a while, it gets timed out and in response kills many a service. This renders my debugging environment useless as when I switch to any other thread, there's no information left to display; no backtrace nothing. I've tried setting `RuntimeWatchdogSec` to 0 in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` which helped me run the debugging session for some more time. However, after that, systemd goes back to killing some udevd service. The only difference is, earlier the timeout was 3s now its 5s